# Rails 3 Automatically Making Joined Table Associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create new entries in a table and automatically create the associated relationship in the joined table.

Here are my models:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_buildings
  has_many :users, :through => :user_buildings
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_buildings
  has_many :buildings, :through => :user_buildings
  ....
end

class UserBuilding < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :building
end
```

Now my user model is also used for devise so I've been using the current_user helper.

To retrieve all the buildings i use

```
current_user.buildings
```

So from there I thought I could use

```
current_user.buildings.build
```

to create a new building associated with the user and update the joined table; however, this only adds the building to the buildings table and doesn't make the association in the user_buildings table.

I have been reading the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html, but I can't seem to figure out the direction I need to go.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a Rails bug to me. `user.buildings.create` does build the correct relationship, while `.build` and `.save` doesn't.

Comment: when you do `current_user.buildings.build`, you should then save as follows: `current_user.save`

Comment: @apneadiving: This only works when you set the :autosave option on the association (see the docs pointed out by @nicholas)

Comment: Thanks guys! Before I read these comments I eventually got it working by making a doing `@building.new(params[:building])`, `@building.save`, then `current_user.buildings << @building` to make the association in the join.  However, using create looks like a much more elegant solution.

Comment: Could you close the questions if you find the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the collection of buildings on current user and rails will handle updating the join table for you.

```
current_user.buildings << Building.new(:some_building_attributes => :some_value)
current_user.save
```